# nextFocusDown won't show keyboard if next edittext inputType="textPassword"

Tags: android, android-edittext, focus

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/account"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:background="@null"
    android:nextFocusDown="@id/password"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textColorHint="@color/_44FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="16dp" />

...

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/password"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
    android:background="@null"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:inputType="textPassword" // if delete this line, everything works
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textColorHint="@color/_44FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="16dp" />
```

Is there any simple property to achieve it?

I don't want to write some like focusListener and showKeyboard etc.